# Is there something like seo for apps?

Tags: seo, keywords, android

I was wondering that Is there something to be done for apps to optimize to view in search results and search engines. Is keyword only thing depend for apps?

Comment: App Store Optimization (ASO)

Answer (score 5):

In short, yes there is. It's big business for a lot of agencies but the basis of it is quite simple. It's a bit like SEO was a few years back - heavy focus on keyword optimisation with a small focus on design.

There's an article on Moz that covers it in a bit more depth that should help you out quite a lot:

https://moz.com/blog/app-store-optimization-checklist